# Correct way to loop through nested XML tags, map them and casting them using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am quite new to XSLT and am wrap my head around a problem. I have an XML document which consists of a certain layout. The part where my problem exists is revolved around the following:

```
<content>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraphs are a possibility</p>
        <image src="base64-encoded-source" />
        <image src="another-base64-encoded-source" />
    </body>
</content>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a proper `JSON` output using an `xsl:map` which could look like such:

```
{
    body-images: [
        "decoded-source",
        "another-decoded-source"
    ]
}
```

I am using XML files which are in the same folder as the XSLT so I select these beforehand and refer to them using the namespace mechanism. I was originally able to achieve the first step of the above JSON example by using `xsl:sequence` which for me looked like:

```
<xsl:if test="not(empty($content/content/body/image))">
    <xsl:map-entry key="string('body-images')">
        <xsl:sequence select="array{$content/content/body/image/@src/string()}"/>
    </xsl:map-entry>
</xsl:if>
```

This was perfect, I managed to fill a map key with an array of the sources from the images. This is however where I realized I had to decode the base64 encoded sources which I have tested and am planning on doing using `saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary('source attribute of image goes here'), 'UTF8'))`.

This is where I am stuck. I had originally tried to place the base64 decoding in the sequence but my editor gave me a warning that I cannot use that form of casting inside the `xsl:sequence`. I have then tried looping through the array which the `xsl:sequence` provided for me using `xsl:for-each` and trying to select my map key, to then use the base64 decoding on the array results one by one. I was unable to figure out what I had to use as key selector however, as the key used by the map is not originally found in the XML document like my other keys.

If my approach is incorrect to begin with feel free to let me know and point me in the correct direction!

Comment: So using `array{$content/content/body/image/saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary(@src), 'UTF8')}` instead of `array{$content/content/body/image/@src/string()}` did not work? Or what exactly did you try and which error message did you get? Is the problem finding the right XPath expression syntax or using that Saxon extension function the right way?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Cheers Martin, it turns out I was using the extension function incorrectly when I first wrote it. XSLT is still a little confusing to me, but the way you wrote it did in fact work. Thank you! EDIT: I originally surrounded everything starting from $content with the saxon extension function which throws: "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value in 'cast as' expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Thanks again to Martin Honnen. It turned out I was using the Saxon extension function incorrectly. Using `array{$content/content/body/image/saxon:base64Binary-to-string(xs:base64Binary(@src), 'UTF8')}` did in fact work and solved my problem.